# Where is the best place to get API calls of what happens to an account?

Tags: api, explorer, stake, unstake

Is there a blockchain explorer like blockchain.info that lets me access an API to do a query if something happens to an account? I want to get a json response of all transactions of an account. Say if I wanted to detect if an unstake transaction happened, I can write a script for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EOSTracker](https://eostracker.io/) is a block explorer that stores actions for users and also provides [an API](https://github.com/EOSEssentials/EOSTracker-API).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `get_actions` filter on a Websocket connection and keep that running, and trigger things on your side with the https://dfuse.io API.